# Generate Code Snippet for functions in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

Platform : ASP.NET Webforms 3.5 with C#
I dont see a snippet for generating functions in C#.

I have one for class, struct and all.
Is that feature not there or am i missing something obvious or is there some other way?

For example, I would like to enter function, then press *TAB* key two times to generate the snippet for function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's none by default but you can simply navigate with Windows Explorer to

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033`

In there select a subfolder, copy paste a snippet, edit it with notepad to do what you want it to do.

Comment: @naveen: No problem. No I'm still busy at forums.asp.net :-).